# Bootstrap navigation bar broken

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have just started learning bootstrap, I am following a tutorial out of the "Joy of bootstrap book" I have the source code for a responsive navigation bar, for some reason (I wrote the code exact, checking it over and over) when you click the button in mobile mode, **Nothing happens**. Im wondering has something changed in bootstrap where this old code(2014-15) does not work?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Custom stylesheet positiond below Bootstrap to alow customization -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
  <!-- Ensures proper rendering and touch zooming -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device.width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="author" content="Michael Barley" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Makes sure user has JavaScript turned on -->
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript in your browser</noscript>
  <!-- Fixed navigation bar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="colapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <!-- Displays three little icons -->
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">example</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <!-- Navigation Pages -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#Specifying">Specifying</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#MarketSectors">Market Sectors</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#EtradingEcomerce">E-trading / E-commerce</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <footer>&copy2016</footer>
  </div>
  <!-- Jquery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typos: See [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="colapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

`colapse` should be `collapse` and possibly the `collapsed` class should be added as well.

Working Example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript in your browser</noscript>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bridgman IBC</a>

    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Specifying">Specifying</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#MarketSectors">Market Sectors</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#EtradingEcomerce">E-trading / E-commerce</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <footer>&copy;2016</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

At this line you should remove the exceeding ">" at the beginning, src is an attribute of the tag script so you have to put it inside the diamond brackets like this. With the code above, the jquery library is not imported.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, however, still having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The script tags syntax is wrong.

First script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Second script:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You have used link tag which is used to link the stylesheets(css) to the html.
The link have a 'href' and the script tag has a 'src'.

Answer (score 0):

You import bootstrap.js with `link rel="stylesheet"` element, replace with `<script src=`